# C# WPF Drag to Reorder Listview

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

How would I drag to reorder a ListView in WPF?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hopefully [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/ListViewDragDropManager.aspx) will help you.

Comment: I don't know about the OP, but it sure helped me.  Thanks.